# C Error During Debugger (Cannot open file: ../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S)

Tags: c, cygwin

I saw a similar question but the answer didn't make any sense to me. Basically what's happening is that during debugging, I get the error Cannot open file: ../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S and it crashes. Weirdly, when I run the getFromMemory() function, by itself, it runs without crashing when I don't use debug mode, but the output is unexpected. (Weird characters.) I'm using codeblocks IDE and the GNU GCC compiler. Not really sure what's going on. Here is the code:

```
int main(){
    char output[200000];
    getFromMemory(0, output, 2);
    printf("output: %s\n", output);
    getFromMemory(0, output, 40000);
    printf("output: %s\n", output);
}

void getFromMemory(int lineNum, char *output, int lines){
    Sleep(10); //sleeps to create a delay when accessing main memory
    //gets bits from memory starting at the specified for a specified number of lines
    //there is a new line every 8 bits
    //not working right now, appears to be doing nothing
    lineNum--;
    FILE *fh;
    fh = fopen("Main Memory.txt", "r");
        char toCombine[lines][10];
    char useless[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < lineNum; i++){
        fgets(useless, 9, fh); //this is done to incrament the file handle by the number of lines specified in lines
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        fgets(toCombine[i], 9, fh);
    }
    int index = 0; //this is used to keep track of what index in output is being written to
    char character; //character is which character in toCombine[] is being read
    int y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        character = toCombine[i][0];
        while(character != '\0'){
            y++;
            output[index] = character;
            index++;
            character = toCombine[i][y];
        }
        if(y == 1){
            //if there is a null terminator at the start of a line (technically there shouldn't even be lines, just a long line of 1's and 0's)
            flags[5] = '1';
            break;
        }
        y = 0;
    }
    output[index] = '\0';
    fclose(fh);

}
```

I put the breakpoint at the line under int main(). I have no idea what the error Cannot open file: ../../../src/gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S
represents. Not really sure what to do about this. Thanks.

Comment: This commonly happens, if you try to single step in a module provided by a library. The module's source is commonly not included in a compiler installation. So just don't do it while debugging _your_ code. -- However, simply ignore that error, let the debugger step out of that part. -- What happens if you set the breakpoint on the call of `getFromMemory()`?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I actually removed the code and changed the way I coded it (am getting another error lol). Is there a way I can learn all this stuff? Like common errors and stuff. I'd like to know what everyone on stack overflow knows I'm just not sure where to go lol.

Comment: I'm sure the most of us are learning by doing. Keep experimenting, read a lot, try a lot, think why things work or do not work, check your mental models. Understand what others do, and why. Keep being curious, that's all. (Said with about 40 years of experience ;-) -- The range of CS is far too broad to understand it all, I gave up some time in the 1980s. Concentrate on the matter that enjoys your the most. -- Anyway, recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: 1) array `flags[]]` is not defined,   2) the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files,

Answer (score 0):

`cygwin.S` is the startup code used by the cygwin linker to prepare the CPU/environment for the execution of your application.

Strongly suggest your run of the debugger looks like:

```
gdb ./nameOfExecutable
break main
run
```

(execution stops at the first line of function `main'
(from this point do what ever is needed to test the executable
(One common scenario is to run the program to completion I.E.

```
continue
```

or single step through the code:

```
step
```

or to step over a function call

```
next
```

or display a (visible) variable

```
print variableName
```

or to quit

```
quit
```

use the help system to get the syntax for the commands

```
help gdbCommand
```

By using various commands to gdb, you can insert start up (command line) parameters, display/change variable values, and  much much more